# How to add a custom field with a random value to all the post

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to add/update a custom field values  for all the post for my wordpress site with the code below ... in phpmysql

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID AS post_id, 'views'
AS meta_key 'RAND(6)*20' AS meta_value
FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'views')
`` AND post_type = 'post';
```

But this is not working at all ....
Can somebody help me with this !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'RAND(6)*20' AS meta_value`, use `RAND(6)*20 AS meta_value`

 Basically remove single quotes.

Comment: Not working ...  showing errors - the sql command itself looks incorrect !

Comment: INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID AS post_id, 'views'
AS meta_key RAND(6)*20 AS meta_value
FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'views')
`` AND post_type = 'post';

Comment: Can you pls check the above sql command  ...Its giving me an error 1

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RAND(6)*20 AS meta_value FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT po' at line 3

Comment: Separate `'views' AS meta_key RAND(6)*20 AS meta_value` with a `,` (Comma)